# Hiding a field column while editing in pyqgis3

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I would like to hide a field column while editing. The following code works perfectly in pyqgis2.

```
def fieldVisibility (layer,fname):
  f = layer.editFormConfig()
  for i, column in enumerate(layer.fields()):
    if column.name()==fname:
      f.setWidgetType(i, "Hidden")
        break
    else:
      continue
```

`setWidgetType` has been superseded and I don’t know the new expression in pyqgis3.

Comment: [@ennine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/87789/ennine), have you seen this article [How can I hide a column in qgis3 using pyqgis](https://tutel.me/c/gis/questions/273385/how+can+i+hide+a+column+in+qgis3+using+pyqgis). By the way `setWidgetType()` now only take a string as the first parameter. Access by index has been removed. (source)[https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html]

Comment: @Many thanks Taras Dubrava for the link. I update the code as mentioned above and it works perfectly.

Comment: The new code should be posted as an **answer** and not edited into the _question_ :)

Comment: [@ennine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/87789/ennine), you are welcome. Do not forget to put **your valid code** as **an answer** to your question.

Answer (score 4):

Following the link mentioned by [@Taras](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/99589/taras), the revise code is as follows:

```
def fieldVisibility (layer,fname):
  setup = QgsEditorWidgetSetup('Hidden', {})
  for i, column in enumerate(layer.fields()):
    if column.name()==fname:
      layer.setEditorWidgetSetup(idx, setup)
        break
    else:
      continue
```